# How to login in to Microsoft 2017 SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I installed MSQL 2017 and I am now trying to follow a tutorial on how to use it.  I can't seem to get it to connect.  I have tried both ".","localhost" and my computer name as my server name. I must have missed a step the Microsoft website and youtube have been no help.  I have attached a screen capture of the error messages.  Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: See [Why am I getting “Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18060667/205233) for things to check and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if SQL Server is running (Use the SQL Server Configuration Manager util)
2. Are you sure about the server name instance?  (Use the SQL Server Configuration Manager util)
3. Check if your fire wall is not blocking the connection

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check services to ensure the server you're trying to connect to is running. if it then right click on SSMS and run as admin.